# Forcing animation on ViewPager

Tags: android, animation, viewpage

I'd like to force the animation triggered by the finger-swipe on a ViewPager - something like, when I press a button outside the ViewPager, it does the fancy animation. 
I've tried something like:

`myPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(myPager, requested_view_id)`
`myPager.computeScroll()`
`myPager.invalidate()`

But it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to have a button or another event move to the "next page" or "previous page" in the `ViewPager` use `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int item)`. This will also show the animation. You will just need to keep track of the current item yourself and then `setCurrentItem(numCurrentItem + 1)`.

Comment: Damn, that was quite obvious wasn't it?lol You rock! Thanks a zillion!:)